# Is “XY nach Deutschland erhalten” proper German syntax?

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure, grammaticality

Does the following sentence violate any German syntax and/or grammar rules? Or more specifically is the preposition *nach* allowed in this case?

> Ich habe […] nach Deutschland erhalten.
>   Ich habe einen Gegenstand nach Deutschland erhalten.

Implying that something was brought along/moved in some way.

- **Example with added context.**

  > Ich habe einen Gegenstand nach Deutschland erhalten, von dem ich nicht weiß ob die Einfuhr legal ist.
- **Example with even more context**

  Another example that – as I would suggest – follows the same basic principles but is far more common for a native to say.

  > Ich habe eine Lieferung nach Deutschland erhalten.

  And I have to clarify: I *wouldn't* write the sentence in my above examples. But I'd argue you *could*.
- **Example with obvious freight/postal context**

  > Ich habe eine Lieferung nach Deutschland (in mein Büro) erhalten, dort werde ich sie morgen abholen.
  >
  > Ich habe einen Gegenstand nach Deutschland (zur Spedition) erhalten, von dem ich nicht weiß ob die Einfuhr nach Österreich legal ist.

  I didn’t add this freight/postal context examples to my question at first since I’m interested in general grammatical rules that allow or prohibit the use of *nach* with a destination and *erhalten* or if you want another verb, like *bekommen.*

  In my opinion the first examples are grammatically correct German sentences. Without defining context of course they are unusual.

Comment: "Lieferung nach Deutschland erhalten" sounds awkward as well; moreover, google gives no meaningful result (unless it means *kostenlose Lieferung nach Deutschland erhalten*, but there you don't get the parcel, you just get the right to send/got a parcel sent for free). Why are you so sure you're right? (now I had to retire my upvote, since I do no longer agree)

Comment: @c.p. please see tofros answer and even better example below. “Ich habe einen Brief nach Deutschland von meiner Mutter erhalten”.

But I didn't want to make the freight/postal context *too* obvious, since I'm primarily interested in the grammar rules that apply, not how common or beautiful the sentence is.

Of course you can say “Ich habe eine Lieferung nach Deutschland erhalten, ich muss sie morgen abholen.” e.g. if you live across the border and have to drive to your office in Germany to pick it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Syntactically*, your sentence is entirely correct - It has a subject, an object, a predicate of movement and a directional preposition.

*Semantically*, however, the sentence is most probably utterly nonsense:

**Nach** as a directional preposition implies "from here to somewhere else" - like in *Ich fahre im Urlaub nach Frankreich*

**erhalten** as a verb of movement means "from somewhere else to here" - like in  *Ich habe einen Brief aus Italien erhalten*

So, verb and preposition conflict (except, maybe, in a constructed case, see below) in terms of "where am I" and "what's moving to where") and so the sentence doesn't make much sense.

In a very constructed case

> Ich habe einen Brief nach Deutschland von meiner Mutter erhalten

Where your mother lives in Mexico, you live in the U.S, and she sent you a letter she wants you to forward to Germany, the sentence *could* probably make sense (I would, however, never try to express such a complicated matter with such a simple sentence).

In a freight forwarder's office (assumed location Germany), sentences like that might be not unusual, though:

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,
>
> wir haben heute Ihre Sendung nach Australien erhalten. Sie wird heute in den Container verpackt und voraussichtlich Ende der Woche verschifft. Ein Avis an den Empfänger geht heute noch raus.

Comment: I had to read your explanation to understand the meaning of the sentences. I would never say "nach Deutschland/Australien" in such a context but rephrase it as "mit Ziel Deutschland/Australien" or "für den Weiterversandt nach D/A".

Comment: @Iris I've added obvious examples to my question, to make the context clear. I didn't at first, since I was – and still am – interested in general applying rules.

Answer (score 2):

This is no more correct than its English equivalent:

> *I have received an item to the U.S.

Receiving things is something that you do *in a particular place*. It's understandable but quite wrong to use *directional* modifiers with such verbs. The idiomatic version would be

> I had something sent *to the U.S.*

since *sending* things naturally takes directional modifiers. German follows exactly the same principle, so you should say

> Ich habe (mir) einen Gegenstand nach Deutschland *schicken*/*liefern* lassen.

Comment: Why U.S.  and not Germany? The English *equivalent* of the OP's sentence is *I have received an item to Germany*, not to *the U.S.*

Comment: It is unquestionably not the most common sentence structure and your last example is of course what you *should* write. But I still don't think there is a rule that would disallow “nach” in my examples. Just as you can say “an der Grenze nach Deutschland” when implying movement.

Comment: You can use "nach" as in your example "nach Deutschland". **But** you can't use "erhalten" combined" with "nach", that's your grammatical error. Kilians last sentence is correct. Alternativly you could say "Ich habe in Deutschland einen Gegenstand erhalten..."

Comment: @IQV So it would also be incorrect to say “Ich habe ein Paket nach Deutschland erhalten” or "Ich habe einen Brief nach Deutschland erhalten"?

Comment: @awenro Yes, these two sentences are both not correct.

Comment: @IQV what makes the syntactical difference to "Ich habe eine Lieferung nach Deutschland erhalten" – which I'm sure is correct?

Comment: I think tofro's answer explains it the best.